# Why Fluentd 1.x is not Creating Index in Elasticsearch 8.7 version?

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd, elasticsearch-8

But with same fluentD confgiurations fluentD is writing data to manual created Indexs in Elasticsearch.

What confgiurations need to be done so that fluentD can create index in Elasticsearch by it's own. I am using https scheme and user name and password with ssl_verify as false and logstash_format:true

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.